# Divs won't center vertically, why not?

Tags: html, css, centering, navigationbar

I'm having trouble with a simple layout for a navigation bar. The icons of the bar are supposed to be both horizontally and vertically centred in their cell.

http://jsfiddle.net/digorydoo/j2v5m7gr/

I just can't figure out what's wrong with my layout.

HTML:

```
<div class="outer-frame">
    <div class="nav-frame">
        <div class="nav-cell">
            <div class="nav-icon">&#127968;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-cell">
            <div class="nav-icon">&#128138;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-cell">
            <div class="nav-icon">&#127915;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* box around everything */
.outer-frame {
position: relative;
/* origin for absolute pos'ed children */
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 12pt;
width: 200px;
height: 190px;
border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
background-color: #fafafa;
}
/* grey area to the left */
.nav-frame {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 36px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
}
/* the outer container of the icon */
.nav-cell {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 36px;
    height: 38px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-top: 4px;
}
/* the inner container of the icon */
 .nav-icon {
    display: block;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    margin:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: I don't even bother trying to figure out what's wrong with my vertical CSS2 alignment anymore.  I just skip straight to flexbox layout and save myself a ton of misery.  If you can, I'd use it.  It will Just Work for this kind of thing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to vertically center a div for all browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers)

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/j2v5m7gr/6/?

Comment: i've read that post, but they use display: table-cell in the answer, which i'm trying to avoid. besides, i want to know how this thing works in my case, because it's a recurring problem, i always run into this sooner or later...

Comment: @j08691: thanks, cool! at least one of the two problems solved, but the icons still aren't centred over their white box. but WHY does setting position:absolute work???

Comment: Put your actual code in the question itself, not just in the Fiddle.

Comment: Do your icons and their containers have a set width and height that won't change? Will you be using something other than `&#127915;` for your final icons? The way that @j08691 is using absolute positioning causes the DIV to stretch out to to the edges of an ancestor element that has positioning applied. You specified a width and a height so it fills it with margin. I have a feeling that your icon is off center as it is inheriting some of it's characteristics from the current font.

Comment: I might be using actual images later, but at the moment these unicodes are what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the ways to center it vertically and horizontally, you need to position it absolutely, set the margin to auto and all four sides to zero (or an offset, but you need to define it):

```
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/j2v5m7gr/7/

> The icons of the bar are supposed to be both horizontally and vertically centred in their cell.

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/j2v5m7gr/10/ The same approach from above.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question at first, but you have the working example in my update.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The latter does indeed center the white boxes in their cells. Now I just want to center the Icons over their white boxes. Maybe I'll be able to figure that myself.

Comment: You're welcome! For icon centering, just set the appropriate width and height and they will center automatically: http://jsfiddle.net/j2v5m7gr/11/

Comment: still not centred in firefox/windows. (of course i could just use offsets or set individual sizes, but i want to avoid that, because it might not look good on a different platform such as android.)

Comment: Just realized my Chrome didn't even render the icons, here it is with the new sizes: http://jsfiddle.net/j2v5m7gr/12/ Try tweaking it a bit more.